# Are all comments deleted while a question is deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-comments, automatic-comments

I had a question marked duplicated then I delete it, but now I want to use a link in a comment in that question but all comments are gone now. Is this normal or a bug or the comments are deleted manually (which should not be true since there is no need to waste time to edit a deleted question's comments)?

Comment: No, comments are either deleted by the poster or a mod. The only exception is the "does this answer your question" comment, which was generated when voting to close as question as dupe. Those get deleted when the question is then actually closed as duplicate. When you delete a post, then the comments are still there, but also still deleted by the poster or a mod.

Comment: @Tom "does this answer your question" that's exactly what I'm talking about. What about add "comments generated automatically" to those comments?

Comment: If the question got closed as a dupe and the comment deleted in the process, then you can find the link from that comment either at the top of the question in a blue-ish box or, if it got reopened prior deletion, in the edit history.

Comment: There would also be a link on the right side of the question under **Linked**. Any time somebody comments or posts the URL to another question, it gets "linked" to the current one. Even removing the comment doesn't remove the link.