# Deleted question but comments are still being notified

Tags: bug

As I understand it, users with 10k will be able to view deleted questions (and as far as I know, the comments that are attached to that question, if they still even exist).

Unfortunately, I don't have the example question as I can't see deleted questions; but in the case for users with rep >= 10k, I am referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/136959499?noredirect=1).  I commented on the question and carried on with whatever I was doing then.  Today, I came back and noticed a response comment notification in my inbox.  However, clicking on it brought me to a "Page not found" page.

I'm not sure if this could be considered a duplicate of [Are all comments deleted while a question is deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392504/are-all-comments-deleted-while-a-question-is-deleted), but my question isn't on the deletion of comments; but when a (non-spam) question is deleted (in some way or another), is it possible that new comments aren't sent to their respective commenter when the commenter can't even see the question.

I think this might be a bit clearer (if my question above isn't).

1. Question is posted.
2. Comment is posted by user (say me with <10k rep)
3. Some time later, the question poster comments on my comments (which sends a notification).
4. Some time later, the question is deleted.
5. I log on, click on the notification that appears but I am brought to a "Page not found".

This is a little frustrating as the question itself had potential.

Would it be possible when a question is deleted, the comment notifications are retracted somehow?  It's pretty useless for the commenter so see the comment notification but can't see the question.